# FFmpeg disable image sequence realtime

Tags: ffmpeg

**Why does using image sequence as input in FFmpeg cause it to insist on realtime encoding?**

For example: I include an image-sequence in a filtergraph, and always get an error about thread message queue blocking:

`[in#0/image2 @ 000000192832d23a] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread queue size option (current value: 8)`

`image2` (the image sequence processor) is implying the thread queue isn't large enough for realtime encoding... but I never intended for realtime encoding.

Options such as `quality` and `preset` and `deadline` all appear to have no effect on this warning persisting.

Warning occurs when executing this command:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i mysequence/%04d.png -loop 1 -i gfx/background.png -filter_complex [0:v]format=rgba -to 10 -ss 5 -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -an out.webm`

If you tell the filter to use [1:v] instead, everything goes fine... but if you target [0:v] - the image sequence - the warning occurs

Why does using image-sequence cause the warning as opposed to a single image?